# Load rows on mouse scroll down in Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net

I was using Telerik Radgrid for cell click functionality and Freeze rows and columns.
It was working fine but if have 100's of records while loading it was taking time to load.

Is there any way to load first 20 rows and on **mouse scroll down** load next rows i.e on scrolling down need to load next rows

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/load-and-append-records

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was Kendo control, in radgrid we does not have Scroll event